# Generate War Java EE Aplication Web Jdeveloper

Tags: model, war, viewcontroller, jdeveloper

I have a Java EE web application on JDeveloper 12.1.2. On this application JDeveloper assistant create two different projects. One for data layer call Model an another one for web layer(View and logic business layer). When I want generate war I only can generate war of one of them and I want create a war which contains both project and deploy this project on my server.

Anyone knows how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view project properties set the dependency to be on the model project.
Then when you create a WAR from the view it will include the JAR from the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an EAR file that can contain both the WARs. To do this, deploy each project to a WAR file. Then at the application level, deploy the app to EAR file. In the 'Edit EAR Deployment Profile Properties' window, go to Application Assembly and tick the individual WARS. Now, you should be able to deploy the EAR with the containing WARs to the server.